# Passing state from react-select <Select> (in function form) to a parent Class

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am attempting to use the react-select "Select" component in my app as a convenient way to generate a series of drop-down lists as part of my UI.

From the react-select documentation, I have been able to get these components to render with the desired options; However, the value stored from the Select components is stored as a state variable via the useState hook.

I need to pass the value (state) of these menus to parent components. I am at a loss of how to get the state value generated in these functions to be able to be read in higher parent components. Below are some snippets of what I currently have.

NOTE: the arrays which populate the options props for these child functions are generated at a higher parent component and passed down as props. There seems to be no issue with a portion of the code

```
function ButtonA(props){
  const options=props.buttonAOptions;
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption]=useState(null);
  
  return(
    
    <div>
      <p>Button A 
      <Select
      value={selectedOption}
      onChange={newValue =>setSelectedOption(newValue)}
      options={options}
      />
     
      </p>
    </div>
     
  )
}

function ButtonB(props){
  const options=props.buttonBOptions;
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption]=useState(null);
  
  return(
    
    <div>
      <p>Button B 
      <Select
      value={selectedOption}
      onChange={newValue =>setSelectedOption(newValue)}
      options={options}
      />
     
      </p>
    </div>
     
  )
}

 class Window extends React.Component {
         constructor(props){
           super(props);
           } 
// there are some other methods in here that are not related to this problem

      render(){
           return (
             
             <div>
             <ButtonA  
             buttonAOptions={this.props.buttonAOptions}
             
             />
             
               <ButtonB 
               buttonBOptions={this.props.buttonBOption}
               />
             
             </div>
               
               )
      }
  }
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I started here. This does not seem to be an option in this case since the react-select component requires setState. I know Redux has a map state to props function, but I dont know how lifting up state helps in this example

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate to a parent component through callbacks. You can lift the state and pass a callback to change the state on the parent, that is also passed as props to your component, or you can maintain the same state on both parent and child and just communicate changes from the children to the parent.

Example:

```js
function Parent() {
  const [counters, setCounters] = useState({ a: 0, b: 0 });

  return (
    <>
      A: {counters.a}
      <Child onChange={(value) => setCounters((s) => ({ ...s, a: value }))} />

      B: {counters.b}
      <Child onChange={(value) => setCounters((s) => ({ ...s, b: value }))} />
    </>
  )
}

function Child({ onChange }) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setCounter((s) => {
      const newValue = s + 1;

      onChange && onChange(newValue);

      return newValue;
    })
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Add 1</button>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I not able to formally upvote the answer, but would if possible. Are there any complications to this approach is Parent is a class instead of a function?

Comment: No complications that I can immediately think of, maybe make sure the callback methods don’t change at every run so you don’t have unnecessary rerenders. It will work the same way with classes. You just create an interface on your child that promise to call back, day to day js.